# Passing dashed argument in Python incorrectly encoding it

Tags: python-3.x

I am sending a Linux command vi `os.system` in Python. The command I am sending contains a dashed argument (`-archive_dir`) however the command is not recognizable in the system as it sees the dash as `\xe2\x80\x93`. How to do dashed arguments, so the dash is seen as what it is, a dash?

```
#cmd im sending
os.system('-archive_dir') <---cmd
\xe2\x80\x93archive_dir <---what linux system sees.
```

Comment: Use UTF-8 not acsii, or more precise use $locale to see your encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your shell is not interpreting the character encoding of the string `'-archive_dir'` correctly. It's important to realize that characters are just bytes, nothing more. Your shell needs to know how to decode these bytes in order to interpret them properly. See [here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) for more details.

I think `subprocess` is a bit smarter about converting to your local character encoding. Although I couldn't find it in the docs, the `subprocess` module is just generally more robust with system calls than the `os` module. It should beat the string into the encoding that your shell expects. It's not possible for me to test in your exact environment, but this is at least worth a try:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["-archive_dir"])
```

if you need to specify multiple arguments (since your argument looks like a flag and not a command), you have to seperate them in the list. For example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ls", "-a"]) # System call: 'ls -a'
```